# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I have an application (Spring 4 MVC+Hibernate 4+MySQL+Maven integration example using annotations) , integrating Spring with Hibernate using annotation based configuration, I see that the schema is automatically created when I start the app. but I don't have this property

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_device_event` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_event_lat` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device_event_lng` float(10,6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `device_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `device_event_message` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `device_event_received` TIMESTAMP ,
  `device_event_coordinates` point DEFAULT  NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `device_id` (`device_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `t_device_event_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`device_id`) REFERENCES `t_device` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and this bean

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_device_event")
public class DeviceEvent {

    public class Coordinates {

        private Double lat;

        private Double lng;


        public Coordinates(Double lat, Double lng) {
            super();
            this.lat = lat;
            this.lng = lng;
        }

        public Double getLat() {
            return lat;
        }

        public void setLat(Double lat) {
            this.lat = lat;
        }

        public Double getLng() {
            return lng;
        }

        public void setLng(Double lng) {
            this.lng = lng;
        }

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="device_id")
    private Device device;


    @Column(name = "device_event_received")
    private Long received;


    @Column(name = "device_event_message")
    private String message;



    @Column(name = "device_event_coordinates")
    private Coordinates coordinates;


    public Coordinates getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(Coordinates coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Device getDevice() {
        return device;
    }

    public void setDevice(Device device) {
        this.device = device;
    }

    public Long getReceived() {
        return received;
    }

    public void setReceived(Long received) {
        this.received = received;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public DeviceEvent(Device device) {
        super();
        this.device = device;
    }
}
```

but i have this error starting the application:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: fr.telecom.model.DeviceEvent$Coordinates, at table: t_device_event, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(device_event_coordinates)]
    org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:336)
    org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:310)
    org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:241)
    org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:496)
    org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:270)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1358)
    org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1849)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)
    org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no match between the column `device_event_coordinates` and it's type in `query` and `DeviceEvent` class.

```
    @Column(name = "device_event_coordinates")
     private Coordinates coordinates;
```

And:

```
  `device_event_coordinates` `point` DEFAULT  NULL,
```